# How to insert data to AWS RDS directly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have created the Mysql instance in AWS RDS.

I want to create a database and insert some data into it by hand directly.

Before I could insert data by Phpmyadmin.

But I lost my way in AWS

I have downloaded the mysql workbench for this. But it fails to connect to the instance with error message ( can not connect to the instance (60) )

I think it happens due to a firewall in AWS

I need the way or app to insert data by hand like phpmyadmin.

Comment: MySQL Workbench is the way to go. You just need to resolve the connection issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firewall you are referring to is the Security Group. Can you select your RDS instance, click on show details and make sure the security group attached to it has the inbound rule on port 3306 for source 0.0.0.0/0 (the best practice would be to only allow access from the ip range you will actually access it from)?

If that is ok, click on the VPC that was created for your RDS instance (still on the RDS details page), and on the VPC's page, on the left menu there is a security group option. There should be a "Created from the RDS Management Console" rule. Check if that is also configured to allow access to port 3306.

With those being allowed, the connection using mySQL Workbench should work. If not, might be something with the credentials in the connection.

Comment: This is assuming that the RDS instance was made "publicly accessible".

Comment: Thanks for your interesting in my question. I did as you said.   And I tried to connect to the RDS instance again with workbench.   I got the following error messages. "Check your SSH connection settings and whether the SSH server is up.
Error: timed out"   and    "ERROR Could not determine remote OS details"       Best Regards

Comment: Quick writing again. I just added as many rules as possible. Then I got the error message "ERROR Could not establish SSH connection: Error reading SSH protocol banner[Errno 54] Connection reset by peer."

Comment: @JinHong When you are trying to connect from workbench, what connection method are you using? Standard TCP/IP or Standard TCP/IP over SSH? If you are trying the second one, try without the SSH. If it works, then its an issue with your SSH configurations.

Comment: Thanks. I could really solve this problem by TCP/IP. Now I can manipulate the instance by myself. Thanks again.

Comment: @JinHong, just a reminder, for better security practices, you should set your security groups both for your RDS instance and you VPC to be access only by the IP ranges you know they should be, instead of 0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's `pyodbc` library:

```
import pyodbc

server = 'tcp:instance.abcd12345.rds.amazonaws.com'
database = 'database4'
username = 'your_username'
password = 'your_Password'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''

                INSERT INTO Table3(ID,LastName,FirstName,Address,City)
VALUES ('444', 'Schwartz', 'Paul','Wilshire Blvd, 2333', 'Los Angeles');

                ''')

cnxn.commit()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Database4.dbo.Table3;")

row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print(row)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```